# How to simplify this SQL query into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a MySQL query that that I'll paste below that returns 5 rows in a set per user. The query looks like the following:

```
select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
  CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) as rank_1 
  FROM fcsusrtbl u 
  INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_1 
  WHERE pr.award_id = 1
  UNION ALL
select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
  CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) as rank_2 
  FROM fcsusrtbl u 
  INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_2 
  WHERE pr.award_id = 1
  UNION ALL
select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
  CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) as rank_3 
  FROM fcsusrtbl u 
  INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_3 
  WHERE pr.award_id = 1
  UNION ALL
select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
  CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) as rank_4 
  FROM fcsusrtbl u 
  INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_4 
  WHERE pr.award_id = 1
  UNION ALL
select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
  CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) as rank_5 
  FROM fcsusrtbl u 
  INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_5 
  WHERE pr.award_id = 1
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here however, is to have `rank_1` through `rank_5` selected as one row versus 5 rows. The following result set for instance:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| firstName | lastName | email                    | rank_1                               |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| bob       | smith    | test@test.com | Vernon Adams - Eastern Washington    |
| bob     | smith    | test@test.com | Timothy Flanders - Sam Houston State |
| bob     | smith    | test@test.com | Brock Jensen - North Dakota State    |
| bob     | smith    | test@test.com | Jeff Mathews - Cornell               |
| bob     | smith    | test@test.com | Walter Powell - Murray State         |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

to this:

`firstName | lastName | email | rank_1 | rank_2 | rank_3 | rank_4 | rank_5`

With `bob` and `smith` and `test@test.com` in one row in addition to each player name under each respective rank column.

Comment: If you really really need them in separate columns it can be done with a tricky `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions like `MAX()` to create a pivot table, but you can also use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return them all separated by some delimiter in one column, then separate them out into individual values in your application code.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` on the `rank_N` value is much easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
(
  SELECT CONCAT(p1.first_name, ' ', p1.last_name, ' - ', p1.school_name)
  FROM fcs_player_rankings pr1 
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p1 ON p1.id = pr1.rank_1 
  WHERE pr1.award_id = 1 AND u.id = pr1.user_id
) AS rank_1,
(
  SELECT CONCAT(p2.first_name, ' ', p2.last_name, ' - ', p2.school_name)
  FROM fcs_player_rankings pr2 
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p2 ON p2.id = pr2.rank_2 
  WHERE pr2.award_id = 1 AND u.id = pr2.user_id
) AS rank_2,
(
  SELECT CONCAT(p3.first_name, ' ', p3.last_name, ' - ', p3.school_name)
  FROM fcs_player_rankings pr3
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p3 ON p3.id = pr3.rank_3 
  WHERE pr3.award_id = 1 AND u.id = pr3.user_id
) AS rank_3,
(
  SELECT CONCAT(p4.first_name, ' ', p4.last_name, ' - ', p4.school_name)
  FROM fcs_player_rankings pr4
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p4 ON p4.id = pr4.rank_4 
  WHERE pr4.award_id = 1 AND u.id = pr4.user_id
) AS rank_4,
(
  SELECT CONCAT(p5.first_name, ' ', p5.last_name, ' - ', p5.school_name)
  FROM fcs_player_rankings pr5 
  INNER JOIN fcsplayers p5 ON p5.id = pr5.rank_5 
  WHERE pr5.award_id = 1 AND u.id = pr5.user_id
) AS rank_5
FROM fcsusrtbl u
```

Comment: Attempting to work with this query, but there is a syntax error somewhere I'm overlooking.

Comment: ***@randombits***, I fixed my answer.  I moved the `u.id = pr5.user_id` to the `WHERE` clause in the sub queries and also inadvertently copied `ON` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data and a schema explanation is a bit difficult to provide a working and efficient solution. I will go for the one that would require the less modifications to the query in order not to risk changing the current logic:

```
select firstName, lastName, email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN numRank = 1 THEN textRank END) rank_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN numRank = 2 THEN textRank END) rank_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN numRank = 3 THEN textRank END) rank_3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN numRank = 4 THEN textRank END) rank_4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN numRank = 5 THEN textRank END) rank_5,
FROM (
    select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
      1 numRank,
      CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) textRank 
      FROM fcsusrtbl u 
      INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
      INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_1 
      WHERE pr.award_id = 1
      UNION ALL
    select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
      2,
      CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name, ' - ', p.school_name) 
      FROM fcsusrtbl u 
      INNER JOIN fcs_player_rankings pr ON u.id = pr.user_id
      INNER JOIN fcsplayers p ON p.id = pr.rank_2 
      WHERE pr.award_id = 1
      UNION ALL
    select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
      3,
    ...
) s
GROUP BY firstName, lastName, email
```